# Security of teamviewer?

Tags: ssh, teamviewer, remote-connection

Teamviewer has 9 digit id numbers and a 4 digit pin.  Assuming at any time that there are thousands of computers online, this makes the 4 digit pin seem kind of dangerous.

1. Is there anything stopping a hacker from randomly attacking and trying 10k pins?
2. If there anything stopping a rogue employee of teamviewer from seeing who is logged in and trying all passwords on a single connection (ie they know the id, and just try to break the password)?

Comment: Why don’t you just use a password?

Comment: “Is there anything stopping a hacker from randomly attacking and trying 10k pins?” - 2FA;  “If there anything stopping a rogue employee of teamviewer from seeing who is logged in and trying all passwords on a single connection (ie they know the id, and just try to break the password)?” - Nope; questions seeking Alternatives to TeamViewer are out of scope.

Comment: TeamViewer will block your requests if you try a password too many times. I'm not sure what the threshold is. I believe there may also be a threshold on attempting to connect to user ID's. Since there are 1 billion possible combinations for user ID's it's harder than you think to just guess one. Then you have the obstacle of not knowing if the password is a pin, or an actual password. It's less dangerous than you're perceiving it to be.

Comment: Theres a couple of things you could tweak in teamviewer so look at this page and follow all the steps but usually its like ramhound said, add a password. You can also add 2way authentication and a couple of other things: https://www.howtogeek.com/257376/how-to-lock-down-teamviewer-for-more-secure-remote-access/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a defense against brute-force attacks, TeamViewer exponentially increases the latency between connection attempts. The attacker gets really discouraged after he has a few false attempts.

See chart here: https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/What-is-Brute-Force-Protection/ta-p/3967

The recommended way to do things is to shutdown the teamviewer client on a machine if you are not using it (temporary client to client) or set your own password instead of using the PIN if it will be for unattended access.